# D3js - can't change style for svg text elemets

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, d3.js

I am using d3.js to create text elements on svg canvas. And I'm trying to change the style of the text. But somehow it doesn't seem to work. Only the x-y coordinate can be changed successfully, but other attributes like font size and color wouldn't change. I've also tried using `.attr` instead of `.style`. Nothing happened. Can anyone help? Really appreciate it!!

```
//create canvas
var canvas = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", 500)
            .attr("height", 500);
//text data
var textSpec = [{"content" : "testing", "font-family" : "sans-serif","font-size" : "80px", "color" : "red" , "x" : 100 , "y" : 15}];
//text display
var text = canvas.selectAll("text")
        .data(textSpec)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x;})
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y;})
        .text(function(d) { return d.content})
        .style("font-family", function(d) { return d.font-family;})
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.font-size;})
        .style("stroke", red)
        .style('fill', function(d) { return d.color;});
```

Comment: Always check console for possible errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is error reported:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: family is not defined
```

because `d.font-family` is not treated as property `font-family` of variable `d` but as property `font` of variable `d` minus `family`.

Also, `red` is used like variable which is not defined.

You have to change the code to:

```
    ...
    .style("font-family", function(d) { return d['font-family'];})
    .style("font-size", function(d) { return d['font-size'];})
    .style("stroke", 'red')
    .style('fill', function(d) { return d.color;});
```